# Get Id Column from XML Attributes

Tags: sql, xml

I have a Table that has a ProductId column and a string column. The string column holds and xml string like this:

```
<Attributes><ProductVariantAttribute ID="149"><ProductVariantAttributeValue><Value>224</Value></ProductVariantAttributeValue></ProductVariantAttribute></Attributes>
<Attributes><ProductVariantAttribute ID="150"><ProductVariantAttributeValue><Value>225</Value></ProductVariantAttributeValue></ProductVariantAttribute></Attributes>
```

but this column is not an XML column.

What I would like to do is query this column and get the ProductId of the row based off the value in between the value tags. So I have 225 but I want to get the ProductId value in that column.

Any way of achieving this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
select d.value('(//ProductVariantAttribute/@ID)[1]', 'int') val
from (select id, cast(xmlstring as xml) data from xmldata) d
cross apply data.nodes('//ProductVariantAttributeValue[Value[1] = 225]') data(d)
```